# How to assign result fro curl to a variable?

Tags: php, curl

I need to do a simple `POST` request and parse the result. For this i use `curl` in `php`. The problem is that i cant assign the result to a variable - it just prints .

My method:

```
private function sendRequest($data)
{
    $ch = curl_init(self::IP . ':' . self::PORT);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec($ch); // HERE IT PRINTS

    curl_close($ch);

    $parsed_result = @simplexml_load_string(trim($result)); // OR HERE IT

    die(var_dump(isset($parsed_result->request_error)));

    if (isset($parsed_result->request_error))
        $this->AJAXResult(TRUE, (string) $parsed_result->request_error->text);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@` sign and see what errors/warnings you may be getting?  I suspect the result is not a well-formed XML and you're getting a warning there somewhere.

Comment: currently there is an error as the result is `true`. @AleksG the problem is that the result of curl is not stored in `$result`, it just prints.

Answer (score 4):

You must add:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)`
if you want curl_exec to return the result of the post request.